# Indexing order based on Hilbert curve in Java

Tags: java, feature-extraction, hilbert-curve

After two days of searching and trying I couldn't implement **[Hilbert Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve)** in java.

I need to fill (for example) 64-pixels into an square-8x8-image based on Hilbert curve. I did the same based on Zig-Zog curve, but (as I suppose to do some feature extraction) the [result](http://jalaldoth.persiangig.com/PEArchive%2828%29sec2.jpg) is not satisfying.

Result:

[image: result]

Can anybody help me out?

**EDIT:**

for example if I gonna write a function to return indexing of square-matrix based on Zig-Zog curve, it would be like this:

```
public class Source {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matrixWidth = 4;
    for (int col = 0; col < matrixWidth; col++){
        for (int row = 0; row < matrixWidth; row++){
            int[] temp = zigZog(row, col, matrixWidth);
            System.out.println(temp[0] + ", " + temp[1]);
        }
    }
}

// >>> zig-zog indexing
public static int[] zigZog(int row, int col, int matrixWidth){
    if (col%2 == 1){
        int[] temp = {((matrixWidth -1) - row), col};
        return temp;
    } else {
        int[] temp = {row, col};
        return temp;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far!

Comment: I did all my work on paper. Actually it didn't much proceed up to coding but I include my function which fills image based on Zig-Zog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that nobody was interested in my Question, I have to do it on my own.

This code blew may return the indices order, based on Hilbert-Curve which I convert it from a python code, which was provided in [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves) (frankly it takes me a while to convert it to Java [no useful auto-converter exists out there], python is really Hard to understand, it seem like it has no structure):

```
public class Source {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int current_square_num = 4;
    int row_num = 2;
    int col_num = 2;
    int arg_num = 2;
    char[][][][] hilbert_map = new char[current_square_num][row_num][col_num][arg_num];

    // >>> 'a': {(0, 0): (0, 'd'), (0, 1): (1, 'a'), (1, 0): (3, 'b'), (1, 1): (2, 'a')}
    hilbert_map[0][0][0][0] = '0';
    hilbert_map[0][0][0][1] = 'd';

    hilbert_map[0][0][1][0] = '1';
    hilbert_map[0][0][1][1] = 'a';

    hilbert_map[0][1][0][0] = '3';
    hilbert_map[0][1][0][1] = 'b';

    hilbert_map[0][1][1][0] = '2';
    hilbert_map[0][1][1][1] = 'a';

    // >>> 'b': {(0, 0): (2, 'b'), (0, 1): (1, 'b'), (1, 0): (3, 'a'), (1, 1): (0, 'c')}
    hilbert_map[1][0][0][0] = '2';
    hilbert_map[1][0][0][1] = 'b';

    hilbert_map[1][0][1][0] = '1';
    hilbert_map[1][0][1][1] = 'b';

    hilbert_map[1][1][0][0] = '3';
    hilbert_map[1][1][0][1] = 'a';

    hilbert_map[1][1][1][0] = '0';
    hilbert_map[1][1][1][1] = 'c';

    // >>> 'c': {(0, 0): (2, 'c'), (0, 1): (3, 'd'), (1, 0): (1, 'c'), (1, 1): (0, 'b')}
    hilbert_map[2][0][0][0] = '2';
    hilbert_map[2][0][0][1] = 'c';

    hilbert_map[2][0][1][0] = '3';
    hilbert_map[2][0][1][1] = 'd';

    hilbert_map[2][1][0][0] = '1';
    hilbert_map[2][1][0][1] = 'c';

    hilbert_map[2][1][1][0] = '0';
    hilbert_map[2][1][1][1] = 'b';

    // >>> 'd': {(0, 0): (0, 'a'), (0, 1): (3, 'c'), (1, 0): (1, 'd'), (1, 1): (2, 'd')}
    hilbert_map[3][0][0][0] = '0';
    hilbert_map[3][0][0][1] = 'a';

    hilbert_map[3][0][1][0] = '3';
    hilbert_map[3][0][1][1] = 'c';

    hilbert_map[3][0][1][0] = '1';
    hilbert_map[3][0][1][1] = 'd';

    hilbert_map[3][1][1][0] = '2';
    hilbert_map[3][1][1][1] = 'd';

    double order = 3;

    for (int col = 0; col < Math.pow(2, order); col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < Math.pow(2, order); row++) {
            System.out.println("(" + row + ", " + col + "): " + point_to_hilbert(row, col, (int) order, hilbert_map));
        }
    }

}

public static int point_to_hilbert(int x, int y, int order, char[][][][] hilbert_map) {
    int position = 0;
    int current_square = 0 /* 'a' */;

    for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
        position = position << 2; // >>> position <<= 2

        int quad_x;
        int quad_y;

        if ((x & (1 << i)) != 0) { // >>> quad_x = 1 if x & (1 << i) else 0
            quad_x = 1;
        } else {
            quad_x = 0;
        }

        if ((y & (1 << i)) != 0) { // >>> quad_y = 1 if y & (1 << i) else 0
            quad_y = 1;
        } else {
            quad_y = 0;
        }

        current_square = 0;
        // >>> quad_position, current_square = hilbert_map[current_square][(quad_x, quad_y)]
        char quad_position = hilbert_map[current_square][quad_x][quad_y][0];
        current_square = Character.getNumericValue(hilbert_map[current_square][quad_x][quad_y][1]);
        // >>> position |= quad_position
        position = position | Character.getNumericValue(quad_position);
    }

    return position;
}

}
```

Enjoy!